# Terminate Parent Function from Ternary Operator

Tags: node.js

I'm attempting to code an HTTP server without ever using an if-statement (please don't tell me to just use if-statements). What I'm trying to do is make a ternary operator force the function that is running it to return and stop running. Here is an example of what I'm trying to go for:

```
let _ = () => {};
let http = require('http');
http.createServer((req,res) => {
    (true) ? terminateParentFunction() : _();
    res.end('test'); // this should not run
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: The question doesn't explain why you need this. Of course, you will be told to use if or other statements - because they do the job. Questions with odd requirements on implementation are supposed to be posted at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ , while SO is for real-world problems.

Comment: Alright, I will ensure to keep this website in mind when thinking about questions related to this one. Thank you @estus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ternary operator involves expressions, while `return` is a statement and cannot be a part of a ternary.

A [short-circuit operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) or a ternary can be used as a part of an expression for  conditional evaluation:

```
false &&
res.end('test'); // this should not run
```

Or

```
true ? 'noop' :
res.end('test'); // this should not run
```

An exception can be used to return from the function early, but it will likely have negative side effects... because it's an exception:

```
true ? (() => { throw 'return' })() : null;
res.end('test'); // this should not run
```

Unless the code is involved in code golf or other discipline that favours potentially unreadable code, the preferable way is to use the thing that is intended for this and can be easily read by any developer:

```
return;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to throw 'return' and catch any error that was just "return", and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yep just return from within a self-invoked anonymous function.

```
let terminateParentFunction = () => { return }
let _ = () => {};
let http = require('http');
http.createServer((req,res) => {
    (true) ? (terminateParentFunction)() : _();
    res.end('test'); // this should not run
}).listen(80);
```